# Why is simple NGINX exact location match failing?

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to use NGINX to route requests with no path (e.g. `http://example.com/` or `http://example.com`) to a particular html file using this config (this is just the relevant section in the server config):

```
root $root;

location = / {
    index index.html;
    alias $root/apps/www/html/main/;
}
```

If I navigate to the site with just the root url (`http://example.com`) I would expect NGINX to return `<root>/apps/www/html/main/index.html` but instead it ignores the exact location and goes directly to the root: all requests come back with the error that `<root>/index.html` cannot be found.

To try to debug this I've tried using different exact location paths (e.g. `location = /foo`) but those are ignored as well. Also I've tried using `root` instead of `alias`, but no success there either.

How do you reroute to a specific location in NGINX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index module will internally rewrite the URI to `/index.html` then restart the search for a matching `location`.

So you either need to provide a `location = /index.html` block to match the new URI.

Or you can process the entire request in a single `location` block by bypassing the index module and using `try_files` instead.

For example:

```
location = / {
    try_files /apps/www/html/main/index.html =404;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.